# Django: "Forbidden (403) - CSRF verification failed. Request aborted" when logging in on Mac only

Tags: ios, django, macos, csrf, verification

I'm rather new to Django and have poured over similar questions here as well as pages and pages of Google results, but have yet to find the cure!

I have a login form on my website that uses CSRF verification. While I haven't had *any* problems on PC/Windows nor Android phones and tablets, I receive the following error when attempting to login on **iPhones and Mac computers**:

> **Forbidden (403)**
>
> CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
>
> More information is available with DEBUG=True.

Although there seems to be some common issues that provide for quick fixes, I believe I have all the bases covered. Then again, as I mentioned before, I'm no Django expert. My settings are as follows:

### settings.py

```py
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
```

### views.py

```py
def default(request):
    if request.user.is_anonymous():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('auth_login'))
    try:
        request.user.voter
    except Voter.DoesNotExist:
        return render_to_response('main/profile.html', {'form': form},
                   context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    return render_to_response('main/ballot.html', {'form': form},
                   context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

### login.html

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="authentication_form" class="uniForm">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|as_uni_form }}
    <div class="buttonHolder">
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="primaryAction" />
    </div>
</form>
```

As a side note, adding 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware' to my setting.py breaks my server and causes a 500 error. Not sure what that means but I figured I'd mention it.

Comment: does `request.user.voter` raise a `DoesNotExist` or an `AttributeError`?  Is there a way you can set `debug=True` and post your 500 error here?

Comment: Which browser? Maybe it is a safari issue..

Comment: Unless you are aqua man or some similar mutant/superhero; you can't pour yourself over anything - you probably meant pore. =]

Comment: @dm03514 - Not that I am aware of.

Comment: @Doboy - Safari, Chrome and Mozilla.

Comment: Do you have `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE` or `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE` set in your production settings?

Comment: What happens if you have CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE=False and SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=True?

Comment: As far as your iPhone is concerned, make sure your iOS Safari browser isn't set to block all cookies.  If it is, you'll get this error.